# How to create scroll function when running out of space

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a console/terminal-like website that runs commands as inputs and then sends a message back. However when I run out of room for commands the console outputs and inputs are not visible (I added a video for reference). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image: The problem]

The html

```
<body>
    <div class=fakeMenu>
        <p>gxzs@terminal</p>
    </div>
        <div class="fakeScreen">
        <div class="output">
            <span>Type "help" for a list of commands.</span>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            <span class="user">
                <span class="blue username">gxzs@terminal</span><span class="colon">:</span><span
                    class="darkblue tilde">~</span>$&nbsp;
            </span>
            <input class="input" autofocus></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./code/script.js"></script>
        </div>
</body>
```

The css

```
  .fakeScreen {
    background-color: #282828;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    vertical-align: center;
  }


.fakeScreen .output {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
```

Comment: You have overflow set to hidden. Try setting `overflow-y: scroll`. Make sure to get rid of the hidden. If you want to hide on x axis, just add `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: @DanZuzevich thanks, that works. do you know any function or something to scroll to the lowest point on the page after an input? I'm using regular js as backend.

Comment: In your JavaScript code, right after you append whatever text into the terminal, scroll to the bottom of the .fakeScreen

Comment: Something like `window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".fakeScreen").scrollHeight)`